# What am I Doing wrong with str_replace ()?

Tags: php, html

Here is the HTML Code :

```
<a href="?loadurl=/search/Battlefield 3/1/99/0/">
  <img src="static/img/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next" />
</a>
```

And this is the PHP Code :

```
//Fix Icons
$toremove = str_replace("next.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\">", "dot.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\"><i class=\"icon-magnet\" style=\"color: #ffdd00;text-decoration: none;\"></i>", $toremove);
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Any help would be appreciated :)

~Kazilotus

Comment: When you write a string that contains double-quote its better to use simple quote to avoid to escape each double quote inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is using XHTML syntax: `<img ... />` but your PHP is looking for HTML syntax: `<img ... >`. You need to make up your mind which to use and stick with it.

For example,

```
$toremove = str_replace("next.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\">", "dot.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\"><i class=\"icon-magnet\" style=\"color: #ffdd00;text-decoration: none;\"></i>", $toremove);
```

Should be:

```
$toremove = str_replace("next.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\" />", "dot.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Next\"><i class=\"icon-magnet\" style=\"color: #ffdd00;text-decoration: none;\"></i>", $toremove);
```

In your sample code.